# SQL query for inserting data into new column

Tags: sql, oracle, testing

I created a new column in a table called emp , by default the new column has all null value .. now i want to copy data of an existing column ,say DEPT_NO present in same table and insert into the newly created column .. what should be the SQL qquery ?

Comment: But why do you want to make a copy column? (`update tablename set newcol = oldcol`)

Comment: Get basic understanding of SQL than asking small questions...

Answer (score 0):

Your sql will be something like this:-

```
UPDATE table1
SET column_new = (select DEPT_NO from table1 WHERE..... ORDER BY......)
WHERE....
```

Here table1 is name of your table and column_new is new column you just added.
Based on the structure and granularity of your table this query will get complex to make correct records. Like you can't insert any dept_no for any employee